# Crash on application - iOS

Tags: ios, crash

I did not know why the application crash. This crash only happen when live to production. But it not happen when i testing with XCode and testing device. Can someone help?

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note: 
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Triggered by Thread:  5
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
>   2.263960     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182bd184c TCP Conn 0x14edc1a00 SSL Handshake DONE
>   7.705489     AppleJPEG                    0x0000000183c5eb54 [0x1500b3400] Releasing session
>   7.705489     AppleJPEG                    0x0000000183c5eb54 [0x14f0b8000] Releasing session
>   7.732061     AppleJPEG                    0x0000000183c5e338 [0x14f0b8000] Created session
>   7.778372     AppleJPEG                    0x0000000183c5e338 [0x1500b3400] Created session
>   8.108716     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182c73104 TCP Conn 0x14ef91720 complete. fd: 8, err: 0
>   8.109137     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182bd175c TCP Conn 0x14edc1a00 starting SSL negotiation
>   8.109635     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182c73104 TCP Conn 0x14edc1a00 complete. fd: 7, err: 0
>   8.110071     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182c74630 TCP Conn 0x14ef91720 event 1. err: 0
>   8.110317     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182c74630 TCP Conn 0x14edc1a00 event 1. err: 0
>   8.998617     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182c73104 TCP Conn 0x14ef5d510 complete. fd: 16, err: 0
>   8.998781     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182c74630 TCP Conn 0x14ef5d510 event 1. err: 0
>   9.010626     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182c73104 TCP Conn 0x14ef92330 complete. fd: 9, err: 0
>   9.010834     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182c74630 TCP Conn 0x14ef92330 event 1. err: 0
>   9.109427     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182c74708 TCP Conn 0x14ef5d510 started
>   9.139106     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182c74708 TCP Conn 0x14ef92330 started
>   9.139106     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182c74708 TCP Conn 0x14ef91720 started
>   9.139106     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182c74708 TCP Conn 0x14edc1a00 started
>   9.149299     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182cc98bc Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
>   9.149299     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182cc9888 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
>   9.149299     CFNetwork                    0x0000000182d1b558 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00000001821814bc mach_msg_trap + 8 1 
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0000000182181338 mach_msg + 72 2
>   CoreFoundation                    0x00000001825b0ac0
>   __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 3   CoreFoundation                   0x00000001825ae7c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032 4   CoreFoundation
>     0x00000001824dd680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384 5   GraphicsServices
>     0x00000001839ec088 GSEventRunModal + 180 6   UIKit
>     0x0000000187354d90 UIApplicationMain + 204 7   AppTest
>     0x0000000100091138 main (AppDelegate.swift:16) 8   libdyld.dylib
>     0x000000018207e8b8 start + 4
>
> Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager Thread
>   1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000018219d4fc kevent_qos +
>   8 1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018206094c
>   _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232 2   libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018204f7bc _dispatch_source_invoke + 0
>
> Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018219cb6c
>   __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182261530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000182261020 start_wqthread + 4
>
> Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018219cb6c
>   __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182261530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000182261020 start_wqthread + 4
>
> Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018219cb6c
>   __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182261530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000182261020 start_wqthread + 4
>
> Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x14edadea0 ::
>   NSOperation 0x14ed2be60 (QOS: LEGACY) Thread 5 Crashed: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018219c140 **pthread_kill + 8 1
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000182264ef8 pthread_kill + 112 2
>   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x000000018210ddac abort + 140 3
>
>   libswiftCore.dylib                0x00000001008117bc 0x100618000 +
>   2070460 4   libswiftCore.dylib                0x00000001007ece14
>   0x100618000 + 1920532 5   libswiftCore.dylib
>
>     0x00000001007ecea0 0x100618000 + 1920672 6   libswiftCore.dylib
>
>     0x0000000100813d00 0x100618000 + 2080000 7   AppTest
>
>     0x00000001000b83c0 Util.storePurchaseRecord(AnyObject!) -> ()
>   (Util.swift:535) 8   AppTest                          0x000000010008a2f0
>   AppViewController.(validateReceipt(AppViewController) -> (()
>   -> ()) -> ()).(closure #1) (AppViewController.swift:1069) 9   CFNetwork                       0x0000000182bdb344
>   __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke +
>   32 10  CFNetwork                      0x0000000182bedcc4
>   __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 296 11  Foundation                       0x0000000182fa0334
>   __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 16 12  Foundation                        0x0000000182ef3100 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 96 13  Foundation
>     0x0000000182ee3348 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 604 14 
>   Foundation                        0x0000000182fa2728 __NSOQSchedule_f +
>   224 15  libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000018204d5f0
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 16 16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182059634 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864 17  libdispatch.dylib 
>     0x00000001820510f4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464 18  libdispatch.dylib
>     0x000000018205b504 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728 19 
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000018205b224
>   _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112 20  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182261470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092 21 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000182261020 start_wqthread + 4
>
> Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader Thread 6: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00000001821814bc mach_msg_trap + 8 1 
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0000000182181338 mach_msg + 72 2
>   CoreFoundation                    0x00000001825b0ac0
>   **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 3   CoreFoundation                   0x00000001825ae7c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032 4   CoreFoundation
>
>     0x00000001824dd680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384 5   CFNetwork
>
>     0x0000000182c4d434 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] +
>   412 6   Foundation                        0x0000000182fbbc40
>   __NSThread__start** + 1000 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182263b28 _pthread_body + 156 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x0000000182263a8c _pthread_body + 0 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x0000000182261028 thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 7: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018219cb6c
>   __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182261530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000182261020 start_wqthread + 4
>
> Thread 8: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018219cb6c
>   __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000182261530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000182261020 start_wqthread + 4
>
> Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private Thread 9: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x000000018219c368 __select + 8 1
>   CoreFoundation                    0x00000001825b7028 __CFSocketManager +
>   648 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000182263b28
>   _pthread_body + 156 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000182263a8c _pthread_body + 0 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x0000000182261028 thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 5 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
>       x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000014ed98c3c
>       x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000f80
>       x8: 0x000000000c000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x00000001a21903a9    x12: 0x00000001a21903a9
>   x13: 0x0000000000000018  x14: 0x000000008000001f  x15:
>   0x0000000080000023    x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000100838088
>   x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006    x20:
>   0x000000016e247000  x21: 0x000000019fcfa570  x22: 0x000000016e246308 
>   x23: 0x000000014ee05f40    x24: 0x000000014ee05f40  x25:
>   0x000000014ef95880  x26: 0x000000014ef85260  x27: 0xa000000000000301
>   x28: 0x000000014ef7f6e0  fp: 0x000000016e246220   lr:
>   0x0000000182264ef8
>       sp: 0x000000016e246200   pc: 0x000000018219c140 cpsr: 0x00000000

Comment: Same issue. Only happens in production. Works fine in development? Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things a CRASH (SIGABRT) implies that you crashed because something caused an abort. The crashed thread traces appears to be an exception caused by an unhandled language exception. In thread 5 it appears that this exception was caused by a call to your Util.swift file to
Util.storePurchaseRecord(AnyObject!) -> () (Util.swift:535). Coming from  AppViewController.(validateReceipt(AppViewController) -> (() -> ()) -> ()).(closure #1) (AppViewController.swift:1069). The most common reasons for these type of crashes are due to an optional being nil, and forced unwrapped or improperly handled.

I would recommend to look through the AppViewController code around line 1069 and Util.swift around line 535. Look to see if in any instance an optional is being forced unwrapped and if so unwrap it with a guard statement.